# Why does PyAudio only play half my audio?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, pyaudio

I am trying to use PyAudio (installed via "sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio") to play a recorded sample multiple times.

I've tried:

```
num_repeats = 6
out.write(numpy.hstack(numpy.tile(d, num_repeats)))
```

but this plays the audio sample only 3 times.  As far as I can hear, it always plays exactly half the data I give it. (e.g if I simply use out.write(d) I only hear half the recorded sample)

There is an obvious work around (num_repeats *= 2) but I would like to understand why this is necessary!

### Full code to reproduce problem

```
import pyaudio
import numpy

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 80000
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
frame = stream.read(CHUNK)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
d = numpy.fromstring(frame, 'int16')

out = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, output=True)
num_repeats = 6
out.write(numpy.hstack(numpy.tile(d, num_repeats)))
out.close()

p.terminate()
```

It behaves the same (i.e. only 3 repeats) whether I use 2 channels or 1.

Comment: I get the same problem, plays exactly half of my audio, any progress with that?

Comment: @Ilanlewin no progress, I've just been using 2 repeats.  My guess is that some part is reading the length of the array in units of 16bits (2 bytes), but then using the number treated in units of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the numpy array to a binary before handing it over. You can use .tobinary() or .tostring()

In case you have matched the datatype this should work.

Comment: Only .tostring() is available in the latest version of numpy, not .tobinary(). This fixes the problem of playing half the audio for me.

Comment: I solved doing it like so: `input_array = np.int16(x).tobytes() 
stream.write(input_array)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved the same issue adding pause before closing the stream. Not sure if it is expected behaviour, but audio on my embedded device was played in async way after writing to the stream. So I had to wait before closing the stream. The setup I finished with was like this:

```
import time
...

#calculate clip duration in seconds
duration = float(clip_data_length) / rate / bytes_per_sample / channels

startTime = time.time()         
stream.write(wav_data)          
endTime = time.time()

if ((endTime - startTime) < duration):
    time.sleep(duration - (endTime - startTime))

time.sleep(0.1)
stream.close()
```